# Seam download control

Tags: jsf, download, seam

I'm using seam and I have a series of web pages all backed with the same action.  On the first web page you have an option to upload a file.  On the last page you confirm some information and then everything is saved.  On this confirmation page I have a link to download the file uploaded in the begining.

This all works fine except the download link wants to take to the user to another page (instead of just downloading the file or opening it in a another window/tab) and if you do follow the link or open it in another tab the backing action is no longer part of the original conversation and thus all the values are null.

Here's my resource  `<s:resource xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
            data="#{myAction.pdf}"
            contentType="application/pdf"
            fileName="#{myAction.pdfName}"/>`

Here's the download control:

```
<s:download src="/exportPdf.xhtml" rendered="#{myAction.hasPdf}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{myAction.pdfName}"/>
    </s:download>
```

Here's the action class:

```
@Name("myAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class MyAction { 
private byte[] pdf;
private String pdfName;
public String getPdfName() {
   return pdfName;
}
public void setPdfName(String pdfName) {
   this.pdfName = pdfName;
}
public byte[] getPdf() {
   return pdf;
}

public void setpdf(byte[] pdf) {
   this.pdf = pdf;
}

public boolean hasPdf(){
  return true;
}
```

The link renders fine with the file name and clicking it does go to the getPdf() method that should return a byte array of the pdf.  Just everything in the backing action is now null.  It seems that the linked resource isn't included in the scope of the original action for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'propagation' attribute of the s:download tag? This should allow you to propagate the current conversation

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a rest service to serve the file and used a standard html link tag targeting "_blank".